# Utility jar is not able to find its dependent jar files. War inside utility jar inside dependents jars

Tags: java, ant, build, classpath, manifest.mf

I am running into some issue, I have developed a utility web service client jar file which is build on springs. Reason behind build this jar its common jar for more than one project.
inside jar we have lib folder its has all its dependent jars. Its working able to load application context and able to do its job independently. Build it as Jar file using ant scripts and its MANIFEST.mf file look like this

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.6.0_45-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Rsrc-Main-Class: ${main-class}
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./lib/com.ibm.jaxws.thinclient_8.0.0.jar lib/com.ibm.
 ws.webservices.thinclient_8.0.0.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar lib/j
 axws-api.jar lib/junit-4.10.jar lib/log4j-1.2.9.jar lib/resolver.jar 
 lib/serializer.jar lib/spring-asm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-beans-
 3.1.0.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-cor
 e-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-expression-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar lib/sprin
 g-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar lib/xercesImpl.jar lib/xercesSamples.jar lib
 /xml-apis.jar
Class-Path: ./ lib/com.ibm.jaxws.thinclient_8.0.0.jar lib/com.ibm.ws.w
 ebservices.thinclient_8.0.0.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar lib/jaxws
 -api.jar lib/junit-4.10.jar lib/log4j-1.2.9.jar lib/resolver.jar lib/
 serializer.jar lib/spring-asm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-beans-3.1.
 0.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-core-3.
 1.0.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-expression-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-te
 st-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar lib/xercesImpl.jar lib/xercesSamples.jar lib/xml
 -apis.jar
```

Now Added that jar file in war file and deployed on web sphere server. Now I am getting

```
[10/12/16 14:48:01:422 EDT] 00001845 SystemOut   XXXX - Add Document has been called 
[10/12/16 14:48:01:425 EDT] 00001845 AxisEngine    E org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine receive null
    org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.createFaultResponse(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.invoke(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:138)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.invoke(EndpointController.java:111)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:161)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doPost(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1632)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1114)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:940)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1820)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:816)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher.invokeTargetOperation(JavaDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.invoke(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:118)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
    at com.nationwide.awd.documents.business.AddDocumentHelper.addDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.dstawd.custom.ws.CLT.addDocumentToFileNet(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
```

Basically its from application to utility jar call. Utility jar not able to find its dependents jar file in its lib

WAR file has utility Jar file in Web-int/lib/
utility jar has its dependents jar in utility/lib/

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks.